# Differentiation question find the normal to the curve

Tags: calculus

Hi I was struggling to this question, can anyone please help me :P

The curve $C$ has equation $2x^2+y^2=18$. Determine the coordinates of the four points on $C$ at which the normal passes through the point $(1,0)$.

I got the gradient of the normal to be: (I called the co-ordinates $a,b$)

$y$ = $\dfrac{b}{2a} \ x+\dfrac{b}{2}$,

then I don't know how to continue, note i found this by differentiating,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate explicitly:

$$4x+2yy'=0\implies y'=-\frac{2x}y$$

So we need points $\;(x_0,y_0)\;$ on the curve s.t. that their normal:

$$y-y_0=\frac{y_0}{2x_0}(x-x_0)$$

passes through $\;(1,0)\;$ , meaning

$$-y_0=\frac{y_0}{2x_0}(1-x_0)\iff-2x_0y_0=y_0-x_0y_0\iff-x_0y_0=y_0$$

1) If $\;y_0=0\;$ then $\;2x_0^2=18\implies x_0=\pm3\;$

2) If $\;y_0\neq0\;$ then $\;x_0=-1\;$ ...and now you continue.

Answer (score 0):

- Differentiate and get slope of tangent (say **m**)
- Then slope of normal = -1/(slope of tangent) = **-1/m**

*Now you have the required slope (in form of x,y) and a point from which it should pass*

- Use point slope form of straight lines **(y-y1)=m(x-x1)** where x1,y1 are the required point from which the straight line should pass and m is the required slope. **NOTE** here **m** is the slope of normal which was found in **2nd step**
- Now you will get some expression in x,y.. get the values of x and y from it and put them in the given equation of curve C

**Also** its an ellipse.. look closely you will see it's along the y-axis so you can directly get two required points by the points which cut the x-axis.. and also the other points will be symmetrical along the x-axis (*say you get x=-1,y=4 then x=-1,y=-4 will also be the required point*) **Only in this case**

So by looking closely you can directly get the answer :)